# Can't access to a variable from a function

Tags: python, function, variables

So i'm trying to make a monopoly game and i have a function called "dice_roll" which is very self explanatory

```
def dice_roll():
    dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    dice1 = int(random.choice(dice))
    dice2 = int(random.choice(dice))
    print("First Dice: ", dice1, "\nSecond Dice: ", dice2, "\nTotal: ", (dice1 + dice2),"\n")
    return dice1, dice2
```

Now what i want to do is to compare the variable that contain the number of the dices so i can keep count of how many double he got but i can't do an if with those values.

```
d = dice_roll()
if d.dado1 == d.dado2:
    doubleBool = True
    double += 1
```

these is what i have the the proble is that when i run the program he runs the function and i don't know why because i'm just initializing a variable.
and then it gives me an error that says "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'dice1'.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: How did you get the idea that you could access the values of the tuple `d` with `d.dado1` and `d.dado2`. Either use `d[0]` and `d[1]` or use tuple unpacking with `dado1, dado2 = dice_roll()`

Comment: @Matthias probably thinking of named tuples https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Returning a value from a function does not bind it to an attribute on said value.

Since `dice_roll()` returns a tuple, `d` is a tuple. You can unpack it directly, making `d` redundant:

```
dado1, dado2 = dice_roll()
```

Comment: but when i run the program it runs the function and i don't want that.
Do you know how to solve that?

Comment: @FilipeMota I don't understand the question. It runs the function because you call the function, `dice_roll()`

Comment: But i just want the values  of the variables so i can check if they are equal or not but don't show it to the console unless i ask so!

Comment: Do i need to take that print out and have a print every time i ask for random numbers?

Comment: @FilipeMota So don't `print` them inside the function

Answer (score 1):

When you return multiple element from a method, they do not become attributs a the variable you save them in, they keep being 2 variables

```
def dice_roll():
    dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    dice1 = int(random.choice(dice))
    dice2 = int(random.choice(dice))
    print("First Dice: ", dice1, "\nSecond Dice: ", dice2, "\nTotal: ", (dice1 + dice2),"\n")
    return dice1, dice2

d1, d2 = dice_roll()
if d1 == d2:
    doubleBool = True
    double += 1
```